# sublime terminus not aligning columns, for example in ls command, or any output with columns

Tags: sublime-text-plugin

I don't know why my terminus doesn't align columns... any setting I should change?
[image]

Comment: Is your font fixed-width? Apart from anything else it should also be filling the whole panel. You may have weird results if you turn word wrap on, for example (though that doesn't look like what's happening here).

Comment: @OdatNurd, thanks, It was the font... I guess I'll try another one...I was using Ubuntu Regular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change the font type to default.